# Why am I unable to scroll the div on mobile/chrome responsive when I scroll up and then down?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that I display for mobile devices, but I have an issue when a user scrolls up from the top of the page and then tries to scroll down, nothing happens.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ao57tyj0/44/

```css
#header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: grey;
 position: absolute;
  top:70px;
  bottom: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
  
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      This is a header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      1Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br> Content goes here Content goes here <br>   Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>     Content goes here Content goes here <br>
      Content goes here Content goes here <br>
      Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>Content goes here Content goes here <br>
    </div>
   </body></html>
```

Gif as example: [image: https://i.imgur.com/LY6iXMD.gif]

If you're in chrome, open the developer tools and go in responsive mode.

The grey block should be scrolled to the top. Then try to scroll up again while holding the mouse button and then move down, nothing happens then.

I'm not able to figure out why this happens

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome. Have you tested it on a _real_ mobile device? Sometimes devtools do strange things.

Comment: As far as testing on a real device, I've created a .html file with the sample code and opened this on Chrome and lightning browser. Same issue as on desktop

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because of jsfiddle lagging (jsfiddle lags very often)

I made a demo and test in localhost with chrome develop tool and my mobile device, it works perfectly.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #header {
      height: 70px;
      width: 320px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #content {
      width: 320px;
      background-color: grey;
      position: absolute;
      top: 70px;
      bottom: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    This is a header
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    1Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br> Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>Content goes here Content goes here
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's also a problem on my mobile browser and on the desktop (not as jsfiddle)